# Create multidimensional dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I try to create a multi dict from a file;

```
k = []
with open('directory file txt',r) as f:
    for line in f:
        k.append(line.strip().split('.'))
```

How can I create multi dictionary like this:

```
dict=[key1][key2][key3][key4]='value'
```

where `key1` is the first element of the first line, `key2` the second, etc.

Comment: Is the "multidimensional dictionary" always of the same depth?

Comment: And `k = line.strip.split('.')` can't be the code you ran ;)

Comment: thankyou for answer. But yes, this works, why not??

Answer (score 6):

Invert the list and nest the results:

```
result = {}
with open('directory file txt',r) as f:
    for line in f:
        keys = line.strip().split('.')
        value = keys[-1]
        for key in reversed(keys[1:-1]):
            value = {key: value}
        result[keys[0]] = value
```

This doesn't deal with keys duplicated 'higher up' all that well; if you have duplicate keys you'd need to use a slightly more cumbersome setup (`defaultdict()` wouldn't handle the situation any better I don't think):

```
result = {}
with open('directory file txt',r) as f:
    for line in f:
        keys = line.strip().split('.')
        current = result
        for key in keys[:-2]:
            current = current.setdefault(key, {})
        current[keys[-2]] = keys[-1]
```